# Change Webstorm emmet behaviour

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to change default behaviour of emmet in Webstorm?
When I type `fs` or `fsi`, default behaviour is `font-style` attribute, but I want `font-size` instead. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebStorm behaves in the same way as Emmet here: `fs` is an abbreviation for 
`font-style:${italic};`, see https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/. You can also try different abbreviations in  https://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/fuzzy-search/#fuzzy-search to see how it's supposed to work.

Emmet toolkit is implemented in many editors, and abbreviations set and fuzzy search algorithms should be the same in all implementations. If the certain abbreviation produces different results in different editors, it would break users expectations. Emmet plugin in Webstorm should behave in the same way as original Emmet, so it's not recommended to change the defaults

Anyway, you can change the way `fs` abbreviation is expanded in **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, Zen CSS/fs**